Modify Recursive Query in Postgresql
select hkodu.id,
       hkodu.hesap_kodu           as hesapKodu,
       case when hkodu.duzenleyici_hesap then concat(hkodu.hesap_adi , ' (-)') else hkodu.hesap_adi end as hesapAdi,
       hkodu.parent_hesap_kodu_id as parentId,
       btc.butce_yili             as butceYili,
       hkodu.active               as active,
       hkodu.owner_birim_id       as birimId,
       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(borc - alacak)
        from tree_hk)             as butce,

       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(alacak)
        from tree_hk)             as alacak,
       (WITH recursive tree_hk AS (SELECT h.id, h.hesap_kodu, h.hesap_adi, h.parent_hesap_kodu_id, b.borc, b.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu h
                                            JOIN butce b ON h.id = b.hesap_kodu_id
                                   where h.id = hkodu.id
                                     and h.active = true

                                   UNION ALL

                                   SELECT hk.id,
                                          hk.hesap_kodu,
                                          hk.hesap_adi,
                                          hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id,
                                          bc.borc,
                                          bc.alacak
                                   FROM hesap_kodu hk
                                            JOIN butce bc ON hk.id = bc.hesap_kodu_id
                                            JOIN tree_hk tr ON tr.id = hk.parent_hesap_kodu_id
                                   where hk.active = true)

        select sum(borc)
        from tree_hk)             as borc

from hesap_kodu hkodu
         left join butce btc on btc.hesap_kodu_id = hkodu.id
    where
(hkodu.owner_birim_id = :birimId)
order by hkodu.hesap_kodu;

In this query, I collect the budget, debit and credit information of parent child accounts in a hierarchical structure from child to parent with a recursive loop. This query returns very late results. Can we do this query in another way instead of recursively? Or could the query be better written in a recursive structure?

You can 1 time calculate tree_hk (sum(alacak) and sum(borc) ) for all accounts (without condition h.id = hkodu.id) and join to hesap_kodu hkodu.

Please review [mre]. Execcutable concrete examples make it much easier for others to offer meaningful guidance. The three recursive queries are identical, so they can be replaced with a single recursive query at the beginning (Common Table Epression).
